# How to open Excel without refreshing data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several connections, that are set to refresh automatically (Refresh Data when opening the file).

I think there is a problem with one of the queries because it hangs upon opening and I can't even see what it is trying to execute.

Is there a way to open the file w/o the auto-refresh?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @JNK: the file itself is .xls, I think it's in 2003 format. I'm using 2007 to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel 2007, you should do the following:

In *Excel Options*, navigate to *Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > External Content*. You'll see the *Security Settings for Data Connections* and *Workbook Links*. Disable both.

Additionally, navigate to *Formulas* tab, click *Manual* under *Calculation* options, and then
click *OK*. Restart Excel and you're done.

In Office 2010, go to the same *External Content* menu, and select *Disable all Data Connections* as well as *Disable automatic update of workbook links*.

Comment: Can you explain the correlation between the data queries being refreshed and the Formula Calculation option? When I have Formulas calculation set to Automatic, running Refresh All results in the queries being executed twice. Changing to Manual makes it run only once. I did not find any definitive resource that documents this behavior.

Answer (score 10):

You can also open the workbook in Protected View. In the open file dialog box, you can click on the down triangle next to the word "Open" and select "Open in Protected View".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don’t see that in my Microsoft Excel **2007** (on Windows XP).  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: i see it in 2010.  it's in the open dialog.  Select a file, then before you click open notice the small triangle on the button indicating its a drop down.  click on that instead, then select one of the options.

Answer (score 3):

OK, in Excel 2007, go to excel options:

`Office Button` -> `Excel Options` at the very bottom.

At the bottom of the `Advanced` options, check "**Ask to update Automatic Links**